# Hibernate Group By Query

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, hql

Please help me understand whats wrong with this query.

```
String sql = "select d.arc_alrt_cde, d.alrt_desc, count(d.arc_alrt_cde) " +
"from arc_alrt a, arc_alrt_def d " +
"where d.arc_alrt_cde = a.alrt_cde " +
"and (a.stat_cde = 'OPEN' or a.stat_cde = 'RE-OPENED') " +
"group by d.arc_alrt_cde, d.alrt_desc "+
"order by count(d.arc_alrt_cde) desc"
println sql
Query query = session.createQuery(sql);
```

Printing SQL

```
sql = select d.arc_alrt_cde, d.alrt_desc, count(d.arc_alrt_cde) from arc_alrt a, arc_alrt_def d where d.arc_alrt_cde = a.alrt_cde and (a.stat_cde = 'OPEN' or a.stat_cde = 'RE-OPENED') group by d.arc_alrt_cde, d.alrt_desc order by count(d.arc_alrt_cde) desc
```

Getting the following error. Tried IN clause also.. Not working..

```
Error:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: node to traverse cannot be null!
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.NodeTraverser.traverseDepthFirst(NodeTraverser.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:300)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:88)
```

Answer (score 1):

That's an SQL query not a HQL one, so you should use:

```
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
```

That exception you got is thrown because Hibernate expects an HQL query but receives an SQL query instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are to name the `count` field such as `count(d.arc_alrt_cde) as countOfXXX`
and also your entity should be aligned with that query or you should remove that `count` field at all.

Answer (score 0):

Changed it to use object properties and it worked. Thanks for your inputs.

```
String sql = "select alert.alertCode, def.alertDesc, count(alert.alertCode) " +
                "from ArcAlert as alert, ArcAlertDef as def " +
                "where alert.alertCode = def.alertCode " +
                "and alert.status in ('OPEN', 'RE-OPENED') " +
                "and alert.assignedTo = '"+assignedTo+"' " +
                "group by alert.alertCode, def.alertDesc " +
                "order by count(alert.alertCode) desc"
```

Query query = session.createQuery(sql);
   lst = query.list()